# morris.js displaying difficulties

Tags: morris.js

I have a morris.js graph. I have a table with 3 columns **id** with values such as 1,2,3 etc, **usernames** with values such as sophie, nick, Paul etc and **timesloggedin** with values such as 69, 58, 4 etc.

I created a chart that has the ids on x and the timesloggedin on y.

What I want is instead of displaying the id number on the bottom of the chart under the bars, to have their usernames. You can see the chart here:

http://kleanthisg.work/chartsnew2.php

CODE:
http://kleanthisg.work/CODE.TXT

table:

[user list:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYpos.jpg)

Comment: add your code here

Comment: Ok. You can see the code above.

Comment: U need to fetch user records from user table

Comment: As you can see above I have the ids, usernames and timesloggedin  in the same table called login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the username and set it as *xkey*

```
Morris.Bar({
 element : 'chart_line_1',
 data:[{ id:'1', timesloggedin:65, username: 'Paul'}, 
        { id:'5', timesloggedin:10, username: 'John'}, 
        { id:'7', timesloggedin:4, username: 'Steve' }],
 xkey:'username',
 ykeys:['timesloggedin'],
 labels:['timesloggedin'],
 hideHover:'auto',
});
```